# Bug in my SQLite based application. using date. Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

All!
My code:
This method needs to check current date and if it is changed it will make new record in db.

```
 public static void updateHintBase(SQLiteOpenHelper database)
    {
        String currentDate = getDateInString();
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("HINTS",
                new String[]{"CURRENT_DATE"},
                "CURRENT_DATE = ?",
                new String[]{currentDate},
                null, null, null);
        int countRow = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        if (countRow==0)
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("CURRENT_DATE", currentDate);
            values.put("SPENT", 0);
            values.put("TOTAL", TOTAL_HINTS);
            db.insert("HINTS", null, values);
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

This method transforms date to String :

```
 private static String getDateInString()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(new Date());
        return date;
    }
```

Table structure:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE HINTS (CURRENT_DATE TEXT PRIMARY KEY , "
                    + "SPENT INTEGER,"
                    + "TOTAL INTEGER);");
```

But my code doesn't work. First time it works, but the second time when date was changed  my first method finds element in cursor anyway...

*For example:*

1) Today 16.01.2017. My application was executed. Everything is all right.

2) Today 18.01.2017. My application was executed and I expect that method **cursor.getCount()** will return to me *0* and new row with new date will be created. But it returns to me *1.* etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I found my mistake!
Word "CURRENT_DATE" is reserved by SQL.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions037.htm#SQLRF00628
That's  why my code works incorrect.
I change "CURRENT_DATE" to "TODAY" an now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set cursor to `cursor.MoveToNext()` You are also closing the cursor before you get the information which may be the problem. Lastly looping through the cursor is the most efficient way to get more that one piece of information.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you...But I closed cursor after getting Count Of Rows. And in another code i really use looping.  But In this code i only need to get the infromation about existing row with current date.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select count(YOUR_ID) from HINTS where CURRENT_DATE = ? ", new String[] {currentDate});
```

Comment: Just now I tryed it. Result  is the same. First time it works. But when I changed date in my smartphone and run application again. Debug mode show that count=1... I saw that row change your self after any query every time...

Comment: you are getting that becuase you are using cursor.getCount(); instead of try to use this if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
 countRow = cursor.getInt(0);
}

Comment: I tried to use what you are writing. It work the same as works before. And now I found my main mistake. Please read my post below.